# ERROR DEPURADOR NETBEANS: Unrecognized or ambiguous flag word: \"?\"

Tags: c, windows, netbeans, depuración

Tengo NetBeans IDE 8.2 instalado junto al paquete de Cygwin en Windows 8.1. Ya he probado reinstalar el programa pero no se soluciona.

Programo en C.

Cuando inicio el programa todo funciona correctamente, los programas compilan y se ejecutan sin dar ningún problema. La excepción es el depurador. Cuando añado un breakpoint e inicio el depurador, siempre me aparecen las mismas ventanas (cuando ya he comprobado que el programa compila y funciona correctamente):

> Signal received: ? (Unknown signal) For program ej9.4, pid 6.148
>
> You may discard the signal or forward it and you may continue or pause the process

**Señal recibida: ? (Señal desconocida) Para programa (nombre del programa)
Puedes descartar la señal o reenviarla y puedes continuar o pausar el proceso

Entonces he probado la opcion DISCARD AND CONTINUE (descartar y continuar) y me aparece la siguiente ventana:

> Debugger error
>   Unrecognized or ambiguous flag word: \"?\".

**Error del depurador. "Flag word" no reconocida o ambigua

¿Tenéis alguna solución para esto? He probado a reinstalar NetBeans y el paquete de Cygwin pero no me da resultado. Si no pulso la opción de DISCARD AND CONTINUE, el proceso de depuración se detiene antes de dar el segundo mensaje de error.

Comment: Yo tenía el mismo problema y lo que hice fue rescatar una copia de cygwin con una versión anterior en la que estaba seguro que funcionaba todo. Fué la única forma de hacerlo funcionar, hoy me ha dado el error en Netbeans 8.2, sigo investigando.

Answer (score 0):

Al parecer es un error de NetBeans y de echo ya hay usuarios que lo han reportado pero al parecer no lo han arreglado desde el 2011, aquí puedes ver que otros usuarios han tenido el mismo problema https://netbeans.org/projects/cnd/lists/users/archive/2011-05/message/115.

Como sugerencia usaría mejor Eclipse para el proceso de la depuración.